# The `mysql`.`proc` table is unavailable. Stored procedures cannot be loaded

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jooq

using **org.jooq.util.GenerationTool** mysql procedures are not getting generated . I am getting "The `mysql`.`proc` table is unavailable. Stored procedures cannot be loaded" .

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that the user you use to generate the MySQL schema is granted access to the `mysql` schema and to the `proc` table in particular.

This issue had also been discussed recently on the jOOQ User Group:

https://groups.google.com/d/msg/jooq-user/WpUnYQSDIlY/lhR8dE68UMgJ